# How do I access my AWS WorkMail account from my Gmail client?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gmail

How do I access my AWS WorkMail account from my Gmail client?

I have a new AWS WorkMail account and need to access it from my Gmail clients, how do I do this (on the web and iOS)?

Answer (score 25):

1. Assuming you WorkMail is correctly working by web interface you need to use SES.

   - From SES panel control select "SMTP Settings" 
     → "Create My SMTP
     Credentials"
     → A window about creating user will show up, select
     'Create'.
   - Select Show User SMTP Security Credentials, it will show you the
     SMTP Username and SMTP Password.
2. From Gmail

   - Setting → Accounts and Import → Add another email address
   - A new yellow window will appear 
     name: (the name you wish to display)
     email address: (xxx@domain.com)
      Alias checked!
3. In the next page:

   - smtp server  smtp.mail.(your-area).awsapps.com  [ex: us-east-1]
     smtp username: (xxx@domain.com) 
     smtp password: (your Workmail password) 
     port:
     465 
     SSL checked.

A confirm mail will be send to (xxx@domain.com), you can easily access by WorkMail web interface. Click the confirmation link and you will be finally able to send mail as (xxx@domain.com) from Gmail.

In the end, if you wish to receive/redirect on your Gmail every mail sent to WorkMail, you need to create an action in WorkMail's Settings.

- Settings → Email rules → New →  Add a Rule name 
  → When the
  message ***is sent to ...*** → Select recipient(s) (xxx@domain.com)

  → ***Redirect the message to ...*** → Select recipient(s) (your@gmail.com)

※ Note: Email rules won't work for recipients in Bcc.

In this way you don't need POP3's setting.
I hope this will help some people.

Comment: I improved the original answer. There was a problem with big attachment [ so don't use: email-smtp.(your-area).amazonaws.com → use: smtp.mail.(your-area).awsapps.com ].
That's all.

Comment: First of all, thank you. It worked perfectly for me but...Why you need User SMTP Security Credentials?

Comment: Because of the 3rd step.
Without SMTP you can't link your aws mail with gmail's configuration. Consequently, without set up SMTP, you can only receive redirected mails from your WorkMail, but you won't be able to send mails from gmail as aws mail address.

Comment: This worked for me, but not with xxx#domain.com and your Workmail password in step 3. Instead, I used the SMPT creds generated in Step 1. Also, I used the server from the SES settings (also in Step 1). When I tried to use workmail email / password in step 3, authentication failed.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately you can not because WorkMail doesn't support POP according to January 2019. Shame to AWS 
[image]

Comment: Wow, I thought for sure Gmail support IMAP as well.  Apparently not!

Answer (score 3):

Note -  You can set it up on **mobile** Gmail application for iOS. I have done so to both send and receive email for multiple WorkMail accounts.

1. Tap profile icon in top right
2. Add another account
3. Other (IMAP)
4. Add username, password, etc. And see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/userguide/using_IMAP.html) for relevant IMAP and SMTP links

Because I was using us-east-1, my info was:

IMAP, 993, imap.mail.us-east-1.awsapps.com

SMTP, 465, smtp.mail.us-east-1.awsapps.com